# How to use database without pre-required program

Tags: database

I want to build a program which needs database to be used in it. Is it possible to use a database without pre-required program and internet access on client computer?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. You should tell us more about your requirements and/pr what you are trying to do. It's hard to guess what you really want (might not be what you think you want).

Comment: I want to attach database to my program in such a way that client computer doesn't need a bulky program and internet access. Is it possible

Comment: Yes. It is possible. The question is, however, if this insight or the answer from Vulcronos helps you any further.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to use a database without requiring internet access is if the databases is on the same computer.

You can bundle a database with your application but then you wouldn't have a central database for everyone to update.  If that fits your requirements, great.  Otherwise you are out of luck.

Regardless, you will need some program to perform persistent storage.  While XML is one option, if you want any database like behavior just do a search on the internet for open source databases you could use if you don't want to pay for Oracle or SQL Server.